# My PC internet speed is slower than it used to be while all of my devices work normally

Tags: networking, performance, internet, modem, desktop-computer

I have around 150Mb/s download speed and around half a year ago I was downloading around 20MB/s and suddenly it went down to 1.2MB/s. Now I thought it might've been because of corona but sadly it still is 1.2MB/s and I checked with multiple speedtest from different websites and all of them say the same. Downloading stuff that is bigger than 30GB takes me almost half a day maybe even more. I have around 5 devices in my apartment and all of them have normal speed but when it comes to my PC  it's way slower than it should be. I use an ethernet cable and the cable stretches throughout 2 rooms. The cable itself is pretty old and I'm thinking it might be it, but I genuinely have no idea. Yesterday I called my Internet provider (UPC) and after I gave them some information they sent a technician today to replace my router but when he checked the internet speed through cable he said everything was okay and there were no problems with the modem itself. I've tried a lot of things - Changing my DNS, to fully resetting the modem and checking if I had some malware problems with my PC as the technician said it. And well nothing helped.. and now Im sort of desparate because I really don't know what is causing this. The modem itself is around 2-3 years old at max.
If anyone could help I'd be grateful.
This is the modem I use if it helps. https://www.upc.cz/televize/doplnky/hd-dvr-mediabox/
Thanks.

Comment: first test with a new ethernet cable ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I'll try. I was thinking of buying a new one so if I can't find any solution other than that then I will invest in new cable.

Comment: Have you tested your connection using a different device with that cable?

Comment: Um no. My PC is the only thing connected with that cable. The cable itself is at least 8 years old minimum, but I'd go maybe even 10. I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ethernet cable is bad causing your computer to detect the network interface as a 10 mb/s connection.
Cables, especially low-quality CCA cables in a fairly humid environment, can degrade over time due to redox reactions between the various metals inside the wires, and it typically takes 8 to 10 year until it becomes a problem.

Other possibility is that the computer is actually configured to use 10 mb/s in stead of auto-detecting the speed.

Either one would explain the approximately 1.2 Mb/s download on that computer.

So check the settings on the network-card in the computer first to see if it is set to auto-detect the speed.
If that is OK replace the cable.

I would replace the old cable anyway for piece of mind. They are cheap.
But make sure you get a CAT 5e or CAT 6 rated cable. Those are suitable for Gigabit connections and with a internet speed of 150 mb/s you need that to make maximum use of your connection.